# How do I make a vertical list go across horizontally?

Tags: html, css, list, header, alignment

I have a portfolio I'm making through Cargo Collective. I'm using one of their pre-made themes but have customized it to my liking. The last thing I'm trying to figure out how to do is align this set of vertical links to horizontal instead.

The site currently looks like [this](http://cargocollective.com/testsite124).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2J3F.jpg) is a mock up I made of what I want i'm trying to get it to look like.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/GNwNpgkd) is a link to the CSS currently on the website.

Comment: You should provide the HTML and CSS in your question.  But look into using `display: inline-block;` on your `<li>` elements.

Comment: use the property "display:inline-block" to achieve this!!

Comment: @Ruddy It would only let me insert two links so I left a comment (see above) of the CSS. That `display: inline-block;` is currently inserted but nothing changed..

Comment: @davidsmith You should take out the relevant CSS and HTML, create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and give us the link. This will get you help quicker. If you do that I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `margin: 650px;` on your `.navigation a`. Add `float: right;` to your `ul` instead and play with margins to get it right.

Comment: That seems to break the links. I added a `display: table-cell;` in the `.navigation span {` and that seemed to align them horizontally but now I need to align the whole thing to the far right and at the bottom of the header... Any advice there?

Comment: Yes, that's because you have a margin: 650px; on your .navigation a. Remove that and float your ul right instead and add some margin there instead. I'll update my answer.